# データベースから取得した時間を表示する際に時差が生じてしまう。デプロイの際に、日本時間で表示させたい。

Tags: php, mysql, heroku

#### 環境

Mac
PHP
ClearDB MySQL
(MySQL Workbenchで操作中)
Herokuでデプロイ

#### 実現したいこと

データベースから情報を取得し、デプロイの際に、日本時間で表示させたい

#### 課題

表示される時間が日本時間にならず9時間の時差が生じてしまいます。

画像に記載しているようなSQL文を試したのですが、"SUPER特権が付与されていないので変更できない" というエラーが出てきてしまいました。

**設定がUTCのまま:**

[image: 設定がUTCのまま]

### ↓時間の部分に時差が生まれる

**入力時の時間**
11：48(11時48分)
**表示時の時間**
02:48(02時48分)
**時差**
９時間の時差が生じる
[image: 時間の部分に時差が生まれる]

また、PHPプログラムで時間を変更した方がいい場合はどのようにするのがよいのでしょうか。

何かヒントやアドバイスをいただきたいです。
何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

**追記**
データベースの保存内容になります。

[image: データベースの保存内容]

表示内容に関わるソースコードになります

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require 'escape.php';
$_GET['id'] = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id');
$id = $_GET['id'];
$_GET['page_id'] = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page_id');
//データ登録
function createBoard($db, $board)
{
    if (!empty($board['nickname']) && !empty($board['message'])) {
        $statement = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO posts SET nickname=?, message=?,created=NOW()');
        $statement->execute(array($board['nickname'], $board['message']));
    }
}
//バリデーション処理
function validate($board)
{
    $errors = [];
    if (!strlen($board['nickname'])) {
        $errors['nickname'] = 'ニックネームを入力してください';
    }
    if (!strlen($board['message'])) {
        $errors['message'] = '投稿が未入力です';
    }
    return $errors;
}
//ページネーションの作成
function pagiNation($db)
{
    define('max_view', 10);
    $count = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM posts');
    $count->execute();
    $total_count = $count->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $maxPage = ceil($total_count['count'] / max_view);
    //ページ番号の取得
    $page = $_GET['page_id'];
    if ($page === '') {
        $page = 1;
    } else {
        $page = $_GET['page_id'];
    }
    $page = max($page, 1);
    $page = min($page, $maxPage);
    //表示する記事の取得
    $select = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT :start,:max ");
    //1ページ目の処理
    if ($page === 1) {
        $select->bindValue(":start", $page - 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $select->bindValue(":max", max_view, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    } else {
        $select->bindValue(":start", ($page - 1) * max_view, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $select->bindValue(":max", max_view, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }
    $select->execute();
    $list = $select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return [$page, $maxPage, $list];
}
//データの削除
function deleteBoard($db, $id)
{
    $statement = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM posts WHERE id=?');
    $statement->execute(array($id));
}
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $board = [
        'nickname' => $_POST['nickname'],
        'message' => $_POST['message'],
    ];
    $errors = validate($board);
    if (!count($errors)) {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: データベースが稼働しているサーバの時間が日本時間(JST)ではなくて世界時間(UT)になっているのでしょうね。
JSTは、UT+9時間ですから、取得した日時(UT)に、DATEADDで９時間加えれば、日本時間(JST)になります。

Comment: – Fumu 7さん　調べてみます！ご回答ありがとうございます！

Comment: この記事 [MySQLのタイムゾーンを日本時間に修正する（Herokuも対応できるのか？）](https://qiita.com/kakudaisuke/items/f4b76fbfd7f89992d971) が質問の状況に適用できるかも。

Comment: プログラムで設定した方がよさそうな事がわかりました。ありがとうございます！

Comment: 本番環境で日本時間を表示させる、PHPプログラムの設定が、どうにも上手くいかなので何かヒントをいただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SET GLOBAL time_zone='Asia/Tokyo'` は権限がないかもしれませんが、`SET time_zone='+09:00'` はできるはずです。

データベース接続後に `SET time_zone='+09:00'` を実行すれば良いと思います。

Comment: 再度実行した所、SET time_zone='+09:00'はSETできました。ですが、データを取得した際にUTCのまま本番環境に表示されてしまいます。確認したいのですが、上記の回答はMySQLで実行する想定でしょうか。それとも、PHPのプログラムの中に記載する形でしょうか。

Comment: SET time_zone は MySQL 接続毎に行う必要があります。ですので、PHP プログラム中で MySQL に接続した後に実行します。

Comment: SET time_zone +09:00を設定した時に表示される情報を、本番環境に反映させるにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか。

Comment: 「接続後に SET time_zone を実行する」というのはプログラム内の処理なので、「本番環境に反映させる」という作業は不要です。

Comment: データの保存時間を、UTCではなく、日本時間で保存する方法はありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

接続時に、time_zoneを設定することで解決いたしました！
沢山のアドバイス、ありがとうございました！

```
<?php
function connect()
{
    $db = parse_url(getenv("CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL"));
    $db['dbname'] = ltrim($db['path'], '/'); //pathのみ取り出す
    $dsn = "mysql:host={$db['host']};dbname={$db['dbname']};charset=utf8";
    $driver_options = [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET time_zone='+09:00'"];
    try {
        $db = new PDO($dsn, $db['user'], $db['pass'], $driver_options);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    } catch (PDOException $Exception) {
        die('DB接続エラー: ' . $Exception->getMessage());
    }
    return $db;
}
```